# this program never makes it past the menu choices it continuously ask for a menu option??

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not sure why it keeps asking to enter a menu choice after I enter one!

When I run it consistently asks me to enter a number, but it doesn't run the functions associated with the numbers

not sure if you needed the class butI included it anyway

```
import pickle

class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.__name = name
        self.__phone = phone
        self.__email = email

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_phone(self, phone):
        self.__phone = phone


    def set_email(self, email):
        self.__email = email

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_phone(self):
        return self.__phone

    def get_email(self):
        return self.__email
```

these are the menu options that I have, no matter what number i enter it asks me to enter another number

```
LOOK_UP = 1
ADD = 2
CHANGE = 3
DELETE = 4
QUIT = 5


FILENAME = 'contacts.txt'


def main():

    mycontacts = load_contacts()

    choice = 0

    while choice != QUIT:

        choice = get_menu_choice()

        if choice == LOOK_UP:
            look_up(mycontacts)
        elif choice == ADD:
            add(mycontacts)
        elif choice == CHANGE:
            change(mycontacts)
        elif choice == DELETE:
            delete(mycontacts)

    save_contacts(mycontacts)


def load_contacts():
     try:
        input_file = open(FILENAME, 'rb')

        contact_dct = pickle.load(input_file)

        input_file.close()

    except:
        contact_dct = {}

    return contact_dct




def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print('Menu')
    print('-------------------')
    print('1. Look up an contact')
    print('2. Add a new contact')
    print('3. Change an existing contact')
    print('4. Delet a contsct')
    print('5. Quit the program')
    print()

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    while choice < LOOK_UP or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a vaild choice: '))

        return choice

def look_up(mycontacts):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')

    print(mycontacts.get(name, 'That name is not found'))



def add(mycontacts):
    name = input('Name: ')
    phone = input('Phone: ')
    email = input('Email: ')

    entry = contact.Contact(name, phone, email)

    if name not in mycontacts:
        mycontacts[name] = entry
        print('The entry has been added.')
    else:
        print('That name already exists.')



def change(mycontacts):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')

    if name in mycontacts:
        phone = input('Enter the new phone number: ')

        email = input('New Email: ')

        entry = contact.Contact(name, phone, email)

        mycontacts[name] = entry
        print('information updated')

    else:
        print('not found')

def delete(mycontacts):
    name = input('Enter a name: ')

    if name in mycontacts:
        del mycontacts[name]
        print('Entry deleted')

    else:
        print('That name not found')


def save_contacts(mycontacts):
    output_file = open(FILENAME, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(mycontacts, output_file)
    output_file.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the following function:

```
def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print('Menu')
    print('-------------------')
    print('1. Look up an contact')
    print('2. Add a new contact')
    print('3. Change an existing contact')
    print('4. Delet a contsct')
    print('5. Quit the program')
    print()

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    while choice < LOOK_UP or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a vaild choice: '))

        return choice
```

*First issue*: If the first choice entered is within bounds, it is never returned from `get_menu_choice()`.

*Second issue*: If the first choice entered is **not** within bounds, your while loop just returns the immediate next choice.

*How to fix it*: Move the `return` statement outside the while loop in `get_menu_choice()`. Also, move `choice = get_menu_choice()` to the bottom of the while loop in `main()`, and set `choice`'s initial value to `get_menu_choice()`.

Hope this helps.

P.S. What happens if the choice entered by the user is **not** an integer? What happens if the user enters a character, string, or control character? I would consider additional error-handling for erroneous input.